# Syntax tree for object control construction

Tags: syntax-trees, control

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a syntax tree for this sentence:

*Sue reminded Mary to water the plants.*

I think this is object control, and should be analyzed this way:

*Sue [IP -ed [VP remind [DP Mary] [CP PRO [IP to win the race ...*

How should I draw the syntax tree? *remind* takes two internal arguments: a DP and a CP. So this seems like a double-object construction, which requires a vP (little v) shell, I think.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The tree you give is in accord with classical TG,  I don't know what a "vP" is.  There have been attempts to predict which nominal will be antecedent for "PRO", but I don't think any of them was ever generally accepted.  Suggestion: change "VP" to "vP".

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still confused. It seems that "remind" takes two objects, the DP and the CP. (Or maybe we should say two complements.) How can that be drawn in X-bar format, with binary branching?

Comment: The only hope I see for a binary branching structure is a causative analysis.  I.e., persuade [A] of [S]  = cause [A believe [S]].  Alexander Grosu's 1972 dissertation at OSU proposed lexical decompositions of this sort.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. [Filler to get to 15 characters]

Comment: You need to tell us which theory you're asking about when you ask something this theory-specific. Neither traditional transformational grammar nor alternatives like HPSG or SBCG analyze object control in terms of verb shells at all. Little-v implies you either mean GB with Larson's original shell model, or MP with one of its competing successors, and the fact that you use DP rather than NP implies probably MP, and probably the version of shells derived from UTAH… but we shouldn't have to guess (and possibly waste everyone's time answering in a different framework than you're asking about).